# Unable to get parameter from Ajax MVC4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Ajax call to a controller that should pass the name of a file which is to be deleted. I am new to the MVC4 and Ajax as well. How do I retrieve the value once I am inside my controller. Below is my Ajax call, and the header for my method in the controller.

In debug mode, I find that Request doesn't show my parameter. Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteFiles", "Home")',
                    data: { "DropFile": JSON.stringify(file.name) },  //{ "fileList": JSON.stringify(fileList) },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                });

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult DeleteFiles(){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a parameter to your Controller method with the same name as the property in your Javascript `data` object. Most likely, you won't need to do the `JSON.stringify()` on your `file.name` variable either.

Comment: So I put this in  data: { "DropFile": file.name }, switched my signature to         public virtual ActionResult DeleteFiles(string DropFile) and my controller doesn't debug anymore?